# How do I make this forest tree shorter without making it wider by adjusting the angles?

Tags: diagrams, forest, trees, linguistics

I'm having some trouble with this forest tree, my goal is to get it shorter without making it any wider, by adjusting the angles under CP and VP to be wider. When I try using the calign=fixed angles, the angle changes but the lines get too long, making the tree wider. Is there a way to adjust the angle without the line length changing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
    \noautomath
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{leipzig}
    \newleipzig{verb}{verb}{verb}
    \newleipzig{akt}{akt}{akt}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={s sep*=5, inner sep=0, l=0}
        [TP
            [NP$_f$ 
                [n, roof]
            ]
            [FutP
                [$t_f$]
                [Fut'
                    [\Fut{} 
                        [tə]
                    ]
                    [CP 
                        [C]
                        [TP 
                            [NP$_x$
                                [ma, roof]
                            ]
                            [T'
                                [T
                                    [?∅ \\ \Fut{}]
                                ]
                                [ Asp 
                                    [Akt$_k$  
                                        [\Akt{}$_{st}$]
                                    ]
                                    [VP
                                        [$t_x$]
                                        [V'
                                            [$t_k$]
                                            [V' 
                                                [V 
                                                    [ɖâ]
                                                ]
                                                [NP 
                                                 [afal, roof]   
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can adjust `l sep` for those nodes:

[image]

```
\begin{forest}
    for tree={s sep*=5, inner sep=0, l=0}
    [TP
        [NP$_f$ 
            [n, roof]
        ]
        [FutP
            [$t_f$]
            [Fut'
                [\Fut{} 
                    [tə]
                ]
                [CP, l sep-=2mm % <--- l sep adjusted here
                    [C]
                    [TP 
                        [NP$_x$
                            [ma, roof]
                        ]
                        [T'
                            [T
                                [?∅ \\ \Fut{}]
                            ]
                            [ Asp 
                                [Akt$_k$  
                                    [\Akt{}$_{st}$]
                                ]
                                [VP, l sep-=2mm % <--- l sep adjusted here
                                    [$t_x$]
                                    [V'
                                        [$t_k$]
                                        [V' 
                                            [V 
                                                [ɖâ]
                                            ]
                                            [NP 
                                             [afal, roof]   
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
```